# "mysql for excel" insert statment changes values from excel

Tags: mysql, excel

Using excel 2010, mysql for excel latest version.

Task: update existing mysql table

issue: mysql for excel changes value to 0 (zero) for one column

I can preview the sql statment and find the value and change insert statement but this isn't an option for large data set.

Destination field in mysql has a foreign key set up, see below
foreign key setup
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzmA8MI6FMnwSU9ZbS1QVW94OGM/edit?usp=sharing

Image of excel xls
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzmA8MI6FMnwU1FzS1FYZEo5ZFE/edit?usp=sharing

mysql update insert statement as created by mysql for excel, see the second last field, if i change the 0 to a 1 then it suceeds

error received with below statment is "MySQL Error 1452:

```
Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`quickset_ptracdb`.`activitylist`, CONSTRAINT `FK_ActivityList_ClientList` FOREIGN KEY (`alClientID`) REFERENCES `clientlist` (`cltID`))"

INSERT INTO `quickset_ptracdb`.`activitylist` 
(`alID`,`alName`,`alComment`,`alUOM`,`alPrice`,`alLabCost`,`alMatCost`,`alClientID`,`alExtCode`) 
VALUES (12,'OB Add New Ca To Exist Spl Clsr','Installation of an additional copper cable in an existing non-pressurized splice. Excludes cable setup and actual splicing. Price Per Cable.',4,78.31,0,0,0,null);
```

Changing the above statement to this works:

```
INSERT INTO `quickset_ptracdb`.`activitylist` 
(`alID`,`alName`,`alComment`,`alUOM`,`alPrice`,`alLabCost`,`alMatCost`,`alClientID`,`alExtCode`) 
VALUES (12,'OB Add New Ca To Exist Spl Clsr','Installation of an additional copper cable in an existing non-pressurized splice. Excludes cable setup and actual splicing. Price Per Cable.',4,78.31,0,0,1,null);
```

Comment: Have you tried the recently released excel2mysql program (I am it's author).  I am also familiar with the Oracle plugin and in my testing there are bugs such as this.  I recommend you submit the bug to Oracle.

Comment: Thanks i gave up and use the connector via access, works fine. Your program looks like it is well built and can fill a need, good luck.